# How to use correctly the reference on lstinputlisting command?

Tags: cross-referencing, listings

In my tex I have this command:

```
\lstinputlisting[breaklines=true,label={lst:use_case_ip}]{ch5/code/get.txt}
\captionof{lstlisting}{HTTP Request where string was found}
```

which generate 1.2 value

when I use ref command, like

```
The listings \ref{lst:use_case_ip}
```

I've got 1.4.1 value... that's completely wrong

where is my mistake?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your mistake is that `\caption` is responsible from generating the anchor that the `\label`, `\ref` mechanism will pick for cross-referencing and you are using label before assigning a caption.

Instead of `\captionof`, use the `caption` key; otherwise. the wrong string will be picked for cross-referencing:

```
\lstinputlisting[breaklines=true,caption={HTTP Request where string was found},label={lst:use_case_ip}]{ch5/code/get.txt}
```

You can control the position of the caption using the `captionpos` key (possible values: `b` for bottom, `t` for top):

```
\lstset{
  captionpos=b
}
```

Comment: nice, it works. but It put the caption above the listing... is there an attribute to put it after the listing?

Comment: @DomenicoChiarito Sure: `captionpos=b`.